# Infer LDAP domain for SSH login

Tags: ssh, ldap

We have some SSH servers that our users connect to using a Windows hosted LDAP domain. Currently, we instruct users to log in with usernames in the format of `user@domain@sshHost`, which works fine, but is a little cumbersome.

The server in question is running in a K8s/EKS cluster (it's a bastion host for kubectl/cluster management, hence the requirement for SSH), and we pass in the login domain as an ENV var (to allow it to establish a connection to the LDAP servers).

What I'd like to do is have the server infer the domain automatically for SSH sessions, so that all they need to provide is `user@sshHost`. Does anyone know if this is possible? All of my searches have come up blank so far...

If useful/for context, here's some of the ENV vars passed in:

```
    env:
      KERBEROS_REALM: domain.example
      LDAP_URI: ldap://domain.example
      LDAP_BASE_DN: DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=example
```

and in our SSH conf:

```
# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication yes
```

Thanks!